# Datepicker not working on javascript generated html

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

With jquery, i append some html form inputs to my site on a button click, like these:

```
html  += '<div class="form-group my-4">';
    html += '<span class="left">Date of ending work <span class="carer_help">Required format: 01-01-2000</span></span>';
    html += '<span class="left"><input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" required="required" name="work_end[' + works_row_melleklet + ']" value="'+work_end+'" /></span>';
html += '</div>';
```

You can see, that the input have the datepicker class.
But my problem is, that the datepicker calendar isnt showing up. I think, because the html input, where i wanna use the calendar, is not in the site's source, its just added by javascript on button click.

How can i fix this?

```
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        language: 'en',
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
    });
```

Comment: I guess your function is called before the html is added..

Comment: The html can be added any time by the user. The function is called on the page bottom.

Comment: @JackPHP037 Please check this demo https://jsfiddle.net/a1Leugpq/

Comment: `html += '...'` then what do you do with `html`?   After that line re-init the datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

When you add dynamic inputs to the DOM, you need to re-initialise with the `datepicker` method again.

```
$('body').on('focus',".your_parent_div_name_where_datepicker_is_added", function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
});​
```

Comment: "your_parent_div_name_where_datepicker_is_added" - i dont know, what div i have to give here.

Comment: the class name of html element where you're appending the input.

Comment: But, the browser writes unexpected token error to my browser, about the code you writed. Whats wrong with it?

Comment: can you add your complete HTML?